# Does Power Nap sync Safari bookmarks and browsing history?

Tags: macos

By what I could read in article
How Power Nap works on your Mac
https://support.apple.com/en-gb/ht204032

Power nap seems not to sync Safari bookmarks nor browsing history, at least it's not mentioned in the list of dos.  Anyone can confirm if this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

I did a little test: bookmarks where synced, Safari history was not.
The test: I slept my Mac mini.  visited a couple websites in my iPhone + added two bookmarks on two other websites.  In the morning, I disconnected the Mac from the network, awoke it and saw that:  Bookmarks had been synced.  Safari history wasn't.